# How to find a PID of a process whose name I don't know exactly?

Tags: linux, shell

I can get the PID of a specific process name by

```
pidof$(ps -C netns)
```

but what if I don't know the name of the process exactly?
I can't type something like

```
pidof$(ps -C net*)
```

so is there any wildcard character, or is there another solution?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `-A` (all processes) option and filter the result through `grep`:

```
pidof $(ps -A | grep "net*")
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use `pgrep -l`, eg:

```
$ pgrep -l sh
1821 sshd
2590 ssh-agent
2658 sh
2677 bash
3025 gvfsd-trash
14785 ksh93
17723 ksh93
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `grep` and pip :

```
pidof$(ps -c |grep yor_pattern)
```

Answer (score 0):

try the following and see if you can discover the process as such

This will give you all processes for all users, in a full-format listing

```
ps auxf
```

where :

- axu = To see every process on the system using BSD syntax
- f = fullformat

if the list is too long you can filter if you have an idea of the process name

For example the command below will show you the pids for chrome.

```
ps auxf | grep chrome
```